# Connection Fail - fails with php 7.3 and 8.0 - tried wamp and xampp - attempting to access a sqlserver database

Tags: xampp, wamp, php

here is the entire error:

Connection fail

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IM006 [SQLSTATE] => IM006 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5701 [code] => 5701 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'sodb'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'sodb'. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code] => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. ) )
```

I have successfully installed the following extensions and they show up under phpinfo()

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x86.dll
```

Here is my php code that is throwing this error:

```
$serverName = "***********************";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"*********", "UID"=>"*********", "PWD"=>"*************");
$maxret = 3;
$conn = false;

do {
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if($conn !== false) break;
    sleep(2);
} while($maxret-- >= 0);
```

I have installed ODBC related libraries

I'm working on three different machines, with different IP addresses, all enabled on azure firewall (sql database is on azure). On one of the machines it works, two of the machines generates the error above.

Identical php.ini files on two of the machines and in wamp the listed extensions are the same. On one machine the php script runs, on another it generates an error.

Comment: Consider formatting the log.

Comment: If your SQL Server is not on LocalHost, did you try connecting to it from somewhere else to make sure remote connection is permitted?

Comment: Yes I can connect to the sql server from another machine at another ip, multiple other machines in fact

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to install Microsoft SQL Server Management ...

MSMSS